# Solving Linear Equations in Finite Field

Tags: systems-of-equations, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ be the finite field of 11 elements. Let $C=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_{10})~:~\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_{i}\equiv 0~(\text{mod}11),~\sum_{i=1}^{10} ix_{i}\equiv 0~(\text{mod}11),~x_{i}\in\mathbb{F}_{11}~\text{and}~x_{i}\neq 10 ~ \text{for all}~ 1\leq i\leq 10 \}$. Then find the cardinality of $C$.

Using properties of equivalent Codes, the above problem can be converted into the following equivalent form:

$C=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{8},2x_{1}+3x_{2}+\cdots+9x_{8},8x_{1}+7x_{2}+\cdots+x_{8})\}$, where $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{8}$ run over the values $0,1,2,\dots,9$ and those values of $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{8}$ are omitted which give the digit '10' in either of the last two coordinate places.

Thanks in advance for any help, please.

Comment: Please, avoid chit-chatting in your questions. This doesn't contribute to the question: "During the study, I encountered the following problem. Using the idea of subspace I have tried to solve this problem, but could not succeed. Therefore, I kindly request your valuable help and guidance to overcome this obstacle."

Comment: Since you're considering $x_i\in \Bbb F_{11}$ it's not necessary to write congruences modulo $11$, just write $\sum_{i=1}^{10} x_i = 0$. In fact, strictly speaking, using congruences like that is incorrect since congruence $\bmod 11$ is an equivalence relation defined on the integers, not in $\Bbb F_{11}$

Comment: @jjagmath Okay Thanks, I will take care of it from next time.

Comment: You can edit this question.

Comment: I notice that this is the same as $Ax=0$ where $A \sim 2 \times 10$ and the two row vectors of $A$ are orthogonal and have nonzero norm in F11.  You can redo a portion of linear algebra theory on F11, including linear independence and Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: @Michael Yes, A is parity check matrix of linear code C. But how do we get beyond that?

Comment: If this was in regular Euclidean space, we have matrix $A$ with two nonzero orthogonal rows of size $10$. How many linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ can we find that are orthogonal to those rows? Equivalently, what is the dimension of the null space of $A$?